Password manager that maintains recents list?
Is there a local password manager that automatically maintains a list of recently- or frequently-used passwords separately from seldom-used ones?
Ideally but optionally:

uses psafe3 format
available for Linux, Windows, and Android


Yes: https://www.enpass.io/
this manifests itself as means to sort results (of search entries) to put the recent ones in a separate group above "Rarely" and "Never" used.
Enpass is available for Linux, Windows, Android, yes.  Plus iOS, MacOSX.
Doesn't use psafe3 format, but it's possible to Export from PasswordSafe.  It's a rip the plaster-off thing and invest the time.  I don't regret moving to Enpass since the browser integration is something that I never had with PasswordSafe.
I am not quite sure how frequency of usage is determined it might one of these methods:

You used the browser integration and this clocks a usage
You opened the entry and used a Copy button
You opened the entry


Hrm. It never occurred to me that there might be such a thing as a password manager that isn't free...
